# importRows Google Fusion Tables API

Tags: python, csv, http-post, google-fusion-tables

I would like to import rows from csv file to fusion table using the Google fusion tables API, I read [this reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows), but I don't understand how to post my csv file here: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/---tableId---/import

How should I attach myFile.csv to request in python ?

```
request = urllib2.Request("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/---tableID---/import")
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST'
response = opener.open(request).read()
```

What I already have:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?%s' % \
(urllib.urlencode({'access_token': access_token,
                   'sql': query})),
headers={'Content-Length':0})
request.get_method = lambda: 'POST' 
response = opener.open(request).read()
print response
```

This code adds single rows to fusion table using simple SQL queries, but I need to add 100k rows, so according to [this reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#insertRow) I have to use the [importRows](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows) method and not [SQL insert statements](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#insertRow).

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#ImportingRowsIntoTables) the correct URL to import rows is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableId/import
```

> **Importing rows into a table**
>
> To import more rows into an existing table, send an authenticated POST
>   HTTP request to the following URI (note the **upload** in the URI below):
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableId/import
>
> You must supply the row data in the message body. The row data should
>   be CSV formatted data, though you may specify alternative delimiters.

Probably [this example](https://puravidaapps.com/taifunFT2.php#import) can help somehow.